# User Validation Node.js/MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js, encryption, password-encryption

To give context, I was doing a job test, and my senior asked me to create a system to mass update the workers  turns.Everything was fine until I got stuck in the part where I needed to do the user validation. He asked me to use the entity "Operator" which has the following fields:
`id bigint AI PK  name varchar(50)  user varchar(50)  hash varchar(50)  idType int  atm varchar(50)`
The problem is that when the password is saved or updated, it is saved with a salt in SHA1.
`1c83055bb43b1a0ac47a0320224b22c198aeaf33` or `testeteste`
The code on my backend to consult the database and validate the password is:

```
const queryFinal = `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM operators WHERE user = '${formLogin}' AND atm = sha1('${formPassword}')`;
```

Point is, how can i know/discover the secret, or is there a function in MySQL to encrypt so i can do the validation

I'm kind of lost right now. I hope someone can shed some light on my problem or share some experience on the matter.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't create sql queries with string concatenation of simple replacements. Little [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) sends his regards ...

Comment: Second, what's -- besides using SHA to hash your password, read https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords why you shouldn't do that -- your actual problem? How does the code you have not behave as expected? But of course, if you have a salted hash, you also would need to consider that salt in some way when checking the password. But without further details, it's quite hard to say anything.